# $-2\arcsin\left(\sqrt{1-x}\right)$ and $\arcsin\left(2x-1\right)$ don't differ by a constant?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

When you take the derivative of $-2\arcsin\left(\sqrt{1-x}\right)$ and $\arcsin\left(2x-1\right)$, you get the same result. Which would mean that $\arcsin\left(2x-1\right) + 2\arcsin\left(\sqrt{1-x}\right)$ is a constant. But using the addition and subtraction formulas, you can simplify the result to $\arcsin\left(2x-1\right) + \sin^{-1}\left(2\sqrt{1-x}\sqrt{x}\right) = \sin^{-1}\left(\left(2x-1\right)\sqrt{4x-3}+4\left(1-x\right)\sqrt{x}\right)$, at least for $x$ within $(0.5,1)$. That right hand side is looking not close to a constant. What's my mistake?

Comment: Using $2\sqrt{1-x}\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{1-(2x-1)^2}$ might be less challenging (and error-prone).

Comment: It might help if you state the addition and subtraction formulas you're using. In particular, where does $\sqrt{4x-3}$ (which is imaginary on a good part of the interval $0\le x\le 1$) come from?

Comment: You should get $\frac{\pi}{2}$ when you subtract the two formulas. You should check your work or type in your work. I'll be willing to point out your mistake once you have done that. Is the formula you used correct?

Comment: $$
\arcsin x + \arcsin y  =\begin{cases}
\arcsin( x\sqrt{1-y^2} + y\sqrt{1-x^2}) \;\;;x^2+y^2 \le 1 \;\text{ or }\; x^2+y^2 > 1, xy< 0\\
\pi - \arcsin( x\sqrt{1-y^2} + y\sqrt{1-x^2}) \;\;;x^2+y^2 > 1, 0< x,y \le 1\\
-\pi - \arcsin( x\sqrt{1-y^2} + y\sqrt{1-x^2}) \;\;;x^2+y^2 > 1, -1< x,y \le 0
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let
$\begin{align}y = -2\arcsin\sqrt{1-x} &\Rightarrow \arcsin\sqrt{1-x} = \frac{-y}{2} \\&\Rightarrow 1-x = \sin^2\left(\frac{-y}{2}\right) = \frac{1-\cos(\pm y)}{2}   ~~~(\text{ as cos is even })\\&\Rightarrow \cos(\pm y) = 2x-1 \\& \Rightarrow\sin(\frac{\pi}2\pm y) = 2x-1 \\ &\Rightarrow \pm y = \arcsin(2x-1) -\frac{\pi}{2} \\ &\Rightarrow y = \begin{cases}\arcsin(2x-1) -\frac{\pi}{2} \\ \text{or} \\-\arcsin(2x-1) +\frac{\pi}{2}\end{cases}\end{align}$

---

Of these two we can find that only the first one is permissible.

$-1\le x \le 1 \Rightarrow 0\le1- x \le 1 \Rightarrow 0 \le \arcsin\sqrt{1-x}\le\frac{\pi}{2} \Rightarrow \boxed{0\le -y\le \pi} \text{ or } \boxed{-\pi\le y\le0}$

Considering the first case,

$-\frac{\pi}{2}\le \arcsin(2x-1)\le\frac{\pi}{2} \Rightarrow -\pi \le\arcsin(2x-1) - \frac{\pi}{2} \le 0 \\ \color{blue}{\text{  satisfies the required range of y}}$

Considering the second case,

$-\frac{\pi}{2}\le -\arcsin(2x-1)\le\frac{\pi}{2} \Rightarrow 0 \le \frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin(2x-1)  \le\pi \\ \color{blue}{\text{  doesn't satisfy the required range of y}}$

---

So,

> $ -2\arcsin\sqrt{1-x} = \arcsin(2x-1) -\frac{\pi}{2}$